# Where can I read more about formula (G-T)= -(S-I) -(X-M)? And how is this formula called?

Tags: reference-request

I saw this formula in following context:

> **I want to create Banker State. It's supposed to rely on profit from loans instead of taxes. I would like to keep taxes as low as possible.**
>
> Reply: what you're trying to do wouldn't work unless you
> were running massive trade surpluses (a la Saudi Arabia). The
> government debt represents nongovernment sector equity. (G-T)= -(S-I)
> -(X-M) The government fiscal deficit represents the nongovernment sector's net financial savings. Government trying to build positive
> debt means forcing the nongovernment sector to go into debt simply
> just to pay its tax bill. It doesn't work, it would create vertical
> unemployment & the automatic fiscal stabilizers would push the
> government fiscal's position (which is reaction to nongovernment
> sector spending behavior) into deficit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already answered yourself I am just filling the textbook recommendation:

You could  find more on this in Blanchard et al. Macroeconomics: an European Perspective. You will find this there (assuming based on the question you are looking something at undergraduate level).

Answer (score 0):

It's from sectorial balances. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectoral_balances

https://shadowproof.com/2012/03/07/s-i-g-t-x-m/

Although it's quite strange that I can't find it in my macroeconomics textbook.

P.S. It's also worth noting that positive (G-T) represents government deficit, NOT government proficit. Although the formula can be changed to use (T-G) instead.